# Excel Application download and updating code over internet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to coding, scripting, or even for creating macros. I have been trying to reduce the workload given to me by using VBA and for my coworkers who put the enormous time in repetitions trying to achieve the goal given by managers. I want some help from you guys with some guidance. So I am currently making a basic application in excel for my coworker I have created some code of it to work it will take time but I got one idea I don't know whether it is possible or not. I will give him the workbook once the projects complete from then onwards that workbook will be populated by the data etc I want something like an application to have feature built-in workbook like from one week now I get one idea or a feature I want to add in the workbook how to approach this problem?
I want something like applications that have like pop up and it checks the newer version of the workbook and downloads the code or restructure the code without affecting the data in the workbook.

Comment: What 'over internet' would mean? To send the new version by mail, transfer site etc? You can use remove - import the workbook modules code. But, in order to avoid any code update, a better idea would be to create an add-in. And send to the coworker the new version when you will have it. It will work on the open workbooks, without affecting its own content.  The difference between a xlsm and a xlsa workbook is not too big...

Comment: "over the internet" means when I am done with the new feature I put the worksheet or a patch over One drive or any given local server the other workbook keeps searching if new version is available  if it is then it downloads the new patch without affecting the data of the workshhet

Answer (score 0):

Simple way https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/use-vba-to-download-a-file.146856/

```vb
Public Sub DownloadInternetFile()
'****************************************************************************************************
'   This function is will download a new version of the program.  The function uses
'   the XMLHTTP object to download files directly from HTTP site.   The URL to download
'   and the file name to save as are parameters passed by the calling procedure.
'****************************************************************************************************
'   Version: 1.0
'   Last Modified: 2005-06-16
'   Written by:  ...
'****************************************************************************************************

    Dim StatusMsg As String, FileSize As String, LastModified As String
    Dim HeaderData As String, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date, StateTime As Date
    Dim BinaryData As Variant, BinaryData1 As Variant, BinaryData2 As Variant
    Dim BinaryData3 As Variant, BinaryData4 As Variant
    Dim UnformattedData As String, CurrentState As Variant
    Dim FileURL As Variant, SaveFileAs As String, i As Integer, tmp As Double
    
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
        
    Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set HttpObj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    CurrentState = -1
    
    FileURL = "http://home.comcast.net/~davidawitkin/AdbeRdr60_enu_full.exe"
    SaveFileAs = WSH.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & "AdbeRdr60_enu_full.exe"
    
    StartTime = Now()
    HttpObj.Open "GET", FileURL, True
    HttpObj.Send

    
    CurrentState = HttpObj.ReadyState
    Do Until CurrentState = 4
        CurrentState = HttpObj.ReadyState
        Select Case CurrentState
            Case 1
                StateTime = Now()
                StatusMsg = StatusMsg & vbNewLine & "State 1: " & StateTime & _
                            "Size: " & Len(HttpObj.ResponseText)
                CurrentState = HttpObj.ReadyState
            Case 2
                StateTime = Now()
                StatusMsg = StatusMsg & vbNewLine & "State 2: " & StateTime & _
                            "Size: " & Len(HttpObj.ResponseText)
                CurrentState = HttpObj.ReadyState
            Case 3
                StateTime = Now()
                StatusMsg = StatusMsg & vbNewLine & "State 3: " & StateTime & _
                            "Size: " & Len(HttpObj.ResponseText)
                CurrentState = HttpObj.ReadyState
        End Select
        CurrentState = HttpObj.ReadyState
    Loop

    StateTime = Now()
    StatusMsg = StatusMsg & vbNewLine & "State 4: " & StateTime & vbNewLine & _
              "Size: " & Len(BinaryData)
    MsgBox StatusMsg, 64, "State Change Info"
    
    ' Load the binary data into a variable.
    BinaryData = HttpObj.ResponseBody
    
    ' Specify stream type - we want To save binary data.
    BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    
    ' Open the stream And write binary data To the object
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.Write BinaryData
    
    ' Save binary data To disk
    BinaryStream.SaveToFile SaveFileAs, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    EndTime = Now()

    ' Get header data As a string
    UnformattedData = HttpObj.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length")
    FileSize = FormatNumber(UnformattedData / 1024000, 1, , -1)
    LastModified = HttpObj.GetResponseHeader("Last-Modified")
    StatusMsg = "File Size: " & FileSize & " Mbytes" & vbNewLine & _
                "Last Modified: " & LastModified & vbNewLine & _
                "Binary Data Size: " & BinaryStream.Size
    MsgBox StatusMsg, 64, "HeaderData"
    
End Sub
```

and then run new file with new code struct!
URL shouldn't to be changed! In same version, but in any version you can set a different update URL.

Or Option 2
Create an Option based user form
that can read options from a plain text
and you can download the txt file and so.